# matrix report grand total vary with each time its rows increase or decrees

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

[image][image]I made a matrix report in oracle which works fine after that I made grand totals out of the repeating frame but in main frame which works fine but only thing is that when column increase or decrease its position on report changed mean which column I made total it goes sometime faraway I want that totals field also change there position with matrix column any idea about that if anyone knows that what can I do for thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Punctuation exists for a reason; I suggest you use it. You wrote the whole message as a single, loooooong sentence which is difficult to read and understand.

---

Anyway, the way I understood the problem, it looks as if you'd have to **anchor** totals' fields to *something*; can't tell what exactly. Might be matrix columns, maybe their enclosing frame ... try and see which of these works properly.

Comment: Sorry for formation, I actually made matrix report, than take some totals in right hand, which i take right hand that's are working fine because these are in repeating frame, than on bottom I take some Grand Totals, which now not  moving with above column and really man I don't have concept of **anchor or enclosing** frame I know that its in property pallet but wont know about that how works

Comment: dear I add a picure how it looks like

Comment: You'll find anchor in Paper Layout Editor's **toolbar**. Anchor e.g. the rightmost "green" grand total field to appropriate matrix column (if possible).

Comment: I tried but nothing is happened like now I give pic of layout model please see if you can find something which can explain to you

Comment: when now try to drop anchor it give me frequency below its group